# Creating an array from EditText fields in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity

I need an Array with username and password. The method containing the array needs to return it. I tried the following code but android studio is showing and error when I tried to access the array from another method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static Boolean log_status;

    public  String[] credentials () {
        String Username;
        String Password;
        String login_data;
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText editPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Username = editText.getText().toString();
        Password = editPass.getText().toString();

        String[] log_data= new  String[1];
        log_data[0]= Username;
        log_data[1]=Password;

        return log_data;

    }
```

How can I make the `log_data` array be accessed by another method? Does my code return an array?

Comment: Where is your onCreate? And why create login_data while not using it?

Answer (score 1):

You made a few mistakes, please try this.

```
EditText password,username;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passWord);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    }
    public  String[] LogInfo () {
        String passWord = password.getText().toString();
        String userName = username.getText().toString();

            String[] log_data= new String[2];
            log_data[0] = passWord;
            log_data[1] = userName;

            return log_data;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you access first element of array which is limited to 1

```
  String[] log_data= new  String[1];
  log_data[0]= Username;
  log_data[1]=Password;
```

Increase the size of the array to 2

```
  String[] log_data= new  String[2];
  log_data[0]= Username;
  log_data[1]=Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

`String[] log_data= new  String[1];` creates a Vector with 1 dimension, so I think it should be: `String[] log_data= new  String[2];`

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] log_data= new  String[1];
log_data[0]= Username;
log_data[1]=Password;
```

Your array size is just 1, not 2.

Try changing

```
String[] log_data= new  String[2];
```

Also, if it doesn't solve, can you tell exact error message you are getting ?